# Gas estimation error code -32000

Tags: remix, gas, nft, error, opensea

Trying to mint nft on remix, but I get this error. Also, it seems that others can mint it on polygon scan. Maybe something is wrong with my metamask wallet? Thank you

[image]

Comment: In case of such an error, you need to attach the contract code and how you call it in the transaction

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.